# Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec (inno-setup installer) (still no solution worked)

Tags: python, inno-setup, python-3.5

After building my application (using cx_Freeze), so I got the exe file of my app. **The exe works nice** . Then I made an installation file of my exe using **InnoSetup** , but after installing my installation file (which i got from InnoSetup) and run the app(from desktop icon), it just pops up the error and nothing else:

```
Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
importError: No module named "encodings"
```

My systeme variables are like :

PY_HOME: `C:\Users\saad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32`

PYTHONPATH: `%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs`

Path: `...;%PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Scripts\`

**Notes:** Windows 7 64bit **+** Python 3.5.1 32 bit **+** `encodings` folder exists in python installation folder and my app folder **+** I copied `python35.dll python35.lib python3.dll python3.lib in the project folder` **+** only python35 installed on my pc, and i uninstalled and deleted the other python (python 25)

**Please HELP!**

Comment: How do you *"launch the app"*?

Comment: I meant I run it from its Desktop icon (which I got after installing it of course), I run it also as an administrator but same error

Comment: Does the application work, if you run it from command-line? + Does the application work, if you copy it manually to another subfolder of the same parent folder, where the application is installed (Program Files?).

Comment: I redo all the proccess from py file to installer, then i run it from cmd admin, but same error, then i copied it to subfolder `demos` (`C:\Program files\myapp\demos`) and run it but still same error. Maybe I should copy the whole Lib folder from `python folder` in the app, what do you think @MartinPrikryl  ???

Comment: it's solved but the solutions seems not good.

Answer (score 0):

**it's solved** but the solutions seems not good I think.

**to explain:**

first of all, cx_freeze gave me `build\exe.win32-3.5\` folder where exe file and other files, but also packages folders *(encoding, xml, collections, ctypes and others)* .

During Installer process, I copied all the files ( **but without the packages folders** ) from `build\exe.win32-3.5\` to the installation **because** I thought that after installing, the application will look for them in `<python>Lib` since I already set the system variables correctly! ( I still don't know why!)

**SOLUTION** : in setup.iss (I used InnoSetup ) I did just one `Source` instruction which:

```
Source: "C:\Users\anonymous\Desktop\stage\python3\build\exe.win32-3.5\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Permissions: users-modify
```